# how to gather all created objects of a class in a list c#

Tags: c#, winforms

```
    public Guna2TileButton [] topNav =
    {
      //this.report,
      
       

    };
```

here there are 10 GUNA tile buttons and I want to collect them in an array to help me alter there property active button styling.. I don't want to write 10 if else statement for every button.. array will help me simplify that.. can any one help me

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the class instances created, you can simply include those instances within the the array initialiser:

`public Guna2TileButton[] topNav = { instance1, instance2 };`

Or you can create the objects directly:

```
public Guna2TileButton[] topNav = 
{ 
  new Guna2TileButton() { /* Set properties here */ },
  new Guna2TileButton() { /* Set properties here */ },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can catch all of them with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037716/create-array-collection-of-buttons-from-existing-buttons) syntax:

```
Guna2TileButton = this.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToArray();
```

or

```
List<Button> buttons = new List<Button> { firstButton, secondButton };
```